# ListView with single choice mode want auto select the first item and call its onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview

So I have ListView with the Single Choice mode enable. I have a selector for the background of the list item and it changes correctly to the activated state.

Using .setSelected() doesn't.

Even if I get the view for that list item and set its state to activated it still doesn't work.

So far this is the best solution I have come up with but the setActivated isn't working basically I have duplicated the code of the onItemClickListener but added setActivate().

```
InformationListAdapter adapter = new InformationListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), info.infoSections);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);  
View v=adapter.getView(0, null, null);
v.setActivated(true);

InformationSection item = (InformationSection)lv.getItemAtPosition(0);
InformationWebFragment webFrag = (InformationWebFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.InfoWebFragment);
webFrag.updateDisplay(item);
```

Comment: Is that the code from your onItemClickListener? What are you trying to accomplish with the onClick?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am stuck on it. How have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the `View` which I suppose the line: `View v=adapter.getView(0, null, null);` gives you - then you can do this:

```
v.performClick();
```

That will fire the `onClick`-event and run the `onClickListener` for the specific `View`.

**Edit**

As we discovered in our discussion below one should call:

```
listView.performItemClick(View view, int position, long id);
```

Comment: performClick is returning false which means that it doesn't have a click listener attached but I definitely have a onItemClickListener attached to the listView

Comment: Then the `View` returned from `adapter.getView(0, null, null)` is probably not the one you think.

Comment: It turns out It needs to listview.performItemClick

If you change your answer I can will give you credit.

Answer (score 12):

To autoselect the first item call:

```
listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

Comment: Make sure this should be after bind to the adapter